# A question about the proof of closed and bounded $\Rightarrow$ compactness

Tags: proof-explanation, compactness, real-numbers

A subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is compact iff it is bounded and closed. I am going over the proof of this theorem. To show that bounded and closed implies compactness, the argument follows the following strategy:

1. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be an open cover of $S$.
2. Define $S_x = S \cap (-\infty, x]$
3. $B = \{ x : S_x \text{ is covered by a finite subcover of } \mathcal{F} \}$
4. If $B$ is bounded, then it will yield a contradiction
5. Therefore, $B$ is not bounded and it follows that $S$ is compact.

My question is why $B$ not being bounded implies that $S$ is compact.

My guess is that if $x \in B$, then $S_x$ is covered by a finite subcover of $\mathcal{F}$. $S \subset S_x$ if $x > \sup S$, so if $B$ is not bounded then all the points of $S$ are covered by a finite subcover of $\mathcal{F}$, which implies that $S$ is also covered by a finite subcover of $\mathcal{F}$. One thing that is unsatisfactory with my observation is that according to this view, it would be enough to show there exists $y$ such that $\sup S < y$ and $y \in B$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem

Comment: That is to say that your equivalence does not hold in general.

Comment: Apologies, maybe it is implicit in your question, but you should specify that $S$ is   a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I added the tag [tag:real-numbers] in line with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space#Euclidean_space

Comment: cheers. but I would make it even more explicit in the question.

Comment: Yes! So to summarize all we need to show is that $\exists y$ such that $y > \sup S$ and $y \in B$. Showing that $B$ is not bounded prove the existence of such $y$, correct?

Comment: Actually now I am worried, because "B not bounded" does not imply "B is not bounded above."

Comment: I will be very honest with you. I did not understand that proof. I think we have to use both closedness and boundness somehow. the proof in the wikipedia link I posted is slightly different. do you have a reference for yours?

Comment: Yes, you understand the proof correctly. Step 4 shows that $B$ is unbounded, hence there is $y \in B$ s.t. $\sup S < y$. So, $S=S \cap (-\infty, y]=S_y$ is covered by finitely many members of $\mathcal{F}$, thus $S$ is compact.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting proof outline that I haven't seen before, but the argument would go as follows.
Let $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be closed and bounded. Assume for contradiction that $B$ is bounded above. Then $q:= \sup B< \infty$.
Case 1: $q \notin S$. Since $S$ is closed, its complement is open and we can pick $r>0$ such that $S$ doesn't intersect the interval $(q-r,q+r)$. By definition of supremum, $S \cap (- \infty, q-r/2]$ is covered by a finite subcover of $\mathcal{F}$. But then the same must be true of $S \cap (- \infty, q+r/2]$, which contradicts that $q$ is the supremum.
Case 2: $q \in S$. Then there is an open set $Q \in \mathcal{F}$ and $r>0$ such that $(q-r,q+r) \subseteq Q$. By definition of supremum, $S \cap (- \infty, q-r/2]$ is covered by a finite subcover of $\mathcal{F}$. But then that same subcover with $Q$ included if not already must cover $S \cap (- \infty, q+r/2]$, which contradicts that $q$ is the supremum.
In either case, we have a contradiction, so we conclude that $B$ isn't bounded above. Since $S$ is bounded, there is $N \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $S \cap (- \infty,N]=S$. Pick $M \in B$ such that $M \geq N$. Then we have a finite subcover of $S \cap (- \infty,M]=S$.
While it seems we didn't use that $S$ is bounded below, this is in fact needed to show that $B$ is nonempty, before the argument above can be used